# Validate string for invalid characters

Tags: c++, string, function, validation, input

I was doing some research today of how to validate a string input for invalid characters such as digits, unfortunately with no success. I am trying to validate string for getting customer's name, and check if there are any digits.

```
#include "stdafx.h"                                             
#include <string>               
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

string validateName(string name[], int i)
{
    while(find_if(name[i].begin(), name[i].end(), std::isdigit) != name[i].end()){   
        cout << "No digits are allowed in name." << endl;
        cout << "Please re-enter customer's name:" << endl;
        cin.clear();                                            
        cin.ignore(20, '\n');
    }

    return name[i];    
}

int main()
{ 
    string name[10];
    int i=0;
    char newentry='n';

    do{
        cout << "Plase enter customer's name: " << endl;                                                        
        getline(cin, name[i]);  
        name[i]=validateName(name, i);

        i++

        cout << "Would you like to enter another questionare? Enter either 'y' or 'n': " << endl;
        cin >> newentry;

    } while((newentry =='y') || (newentry=='Y'));
```

The function seems to do the job fine, but only with the first input. For example when I run the program and enter a number 3, an error message will be displayed and user is asked to enter name again. After user enters a valid name, the program however keeps asking for a new input with the same error messages even if no digits or special characters are used.

Comment: off topic. y passing string array to fn? pass only the string.

Comment: And why use array when you can use `std::vector` ?

Comment: If I won't pass string array it will not work otherwise.

Comment: vector? I've never used these before. I am still a noob.

Comment: If I think I'm following you correctly, you should not be incrementing `i` until you get a valid name. Your name is not valid but yet you move on to get the next name.

Comment: There are other functions for validating integers in my program, and I pass 'i' just fine to them. That is the whole idea of having an external function in order to validate the input. So the same input will keep looping until user enters a valid one, then its being returned, and only then i is being increased.

Comment: Do you really want many names or just one?

Comment: I need many as it is stated in the assessment

Comment: 'a string'. ok so 1 then... so why the array of strings?

Comment: You mean array of strings in the main or the function for validating them? If in main, where else I will store multiple inputs from the user, if for the validating function, I cannot just pass single array as the compiler displays errors.

Comment: It's the same array. And after you 'validate' each name you're just keeping it anyway

Comment: What should I do then, remove [i] ? As I said, if I do so compiler displays an error message and cannot compile.

Answer (score 3):

I have changed your code a little, but as it is already very late and I have to go to university tomorrow, I'll leave it up to you to see what I did:

```
#include <string>               
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void validateName(string &name) //Pass by reference and edit given string not a copy, so there is no need to return it
{
    cout << "Plase enter customer's name: " << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    getline(cin, name);
    while (name.find_first_of("0123456789") != -1)
    {
        cout << "No digits are allowed in name." << endl;
        cout << "Please re-enter customer's name:" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        getline(cin, name);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string name[10];
    int i = 0;
    char newentry = 'n';

    do{
        validateName(name[i++]);

        if (i >= 10)
            break;

        cout << "Would you like to enter another questionare? Enter either 'y' or 'n': " << endl;

        do{
            cin.clear();
            cin.sync();
            cin >> newentry;
        } while ((newentry != 'y') && (newentry != 'Y') && (newentry != 'n') && (newentry != 'N'));

    } while ((newentry == 'y') || (newentry == 'Y'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function validateName does not have an exit from the loop if the name is incorrect and contains digits.

I think you forgot to place `getline` in this loop to reenter the name.

Also insert statement

```
cin.ignore(20, '\n');
```

before

```
getline(cin, name[i]);
```

in the do-while loop.

Or even better to use

```
cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() );
```

The problem is that in the end of the loop there is statement

```
cin >> newentry;
```

which places the the new line character in the input buffer and the next getline reads nothing.

Comment: Makes no difference :(

Comment: @noobuser333 You function has infinite loop because there is no exit from the function if the name is incorrect.

Comment: Of course if the name is incorrect I'd want the user to enter a new, valid name. Only when its valid it should return to the int main and follow with the rest of the program.